# Issues mapping lists after upgrade from 7.0.1 to 8.1.1?

Tags: .net-core, automapper

I've been tasked with upgrading automapper. We are currently on version `7.0.1` and i'm upgrading to `8.1.1`. I'm pretty green at automapper so bear with me here. After doing the upgrade and calling `mc.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` i get the following type of errors:

```
{"The following member on Trs.Gemini.EmployerService.Models.Cba.TaskListDto cannot be mapped: \n\tTasks \nAdd a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type Trs.Gemini.EmployerService.Models.Cba.TaskListDto.\nContext:\n\tMapping to member Tasks from Trs.Gemini.EmployerService.Api.UseCases.Cba.Queries.GetTrsUserTaskListResult to Trs.Gemini.EmployerService.Models.Cba.TaskListDto\nException of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' was thrown."}
{"The following member on Trs.Gemini.EmployerService.Models.Cba.TaskListDto cannot be mapped: \n\tTasks \nAdd a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type Trs.Gemini.EmployerService.Models.Cba.TaskListDto.\nContext:\n\tMapping to member Tasks from Trs.Gemini.EmployerService.Api.UseCases.Cba.Queries.GetEmployerTaskListResult to Trs.Gemini.EmployerService.Models.Cba.TaskListDto\nException of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' was thrown."}
```

```cs
CreateMap<GetTrsUserTaskListResult, TaskListDto>(MemberList.Source)
                .ForMember(x => x.Tasks, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.TrsUserTaskResults));

            CreateMap<GetEmployerTaskListResult, TaskListDto>(MemberList.Source)
                .ForMember(x => x.Tasks, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.EmployerTaskResults));
```

```cs
    public class GetTrsUserTaskListResult
    {
        public GetTrsUserTaskListResult()
        {
            TrsUserTaskResults = new List<GetTaskResult>();
        }

        public Guid? TrsUserKey { get; set; }
        public List<GetTaskResult> TrsUserTaskResults { get; set; }
        public int TotalResultsCount { get; set; }
        public int FilteredResultsCount { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
    public class TaskListDto
    {
        public TaskListDto()
        {
            Tasks = new List<TaskDto>();
        }

        public Guid? TrsUserKey { get; set; }
        public List<TaskDto> Tasks { get; set; }
        public int TotalResultsCount { get; set; }
        public int FilteredResultsCount { get; set; }
    }
```

```cs
    public class GetEmployerTaskListResult
    {
        public GetEmployerTaskListResult()
        {
           EmployerTaskResults = new List<GetTaskResult>();
        }
        public List<GetTaskResult> EmployerTaskResults { get; set; }

        public int TotalResultsCount { get; set; }
        public int FilteredResultsCount { get; set; }
    }
```

This is only a sample. There are more of these type of errors but the common theme seems to be it always seems to be a `List<x>` in the underlying classes that it has issues with. This code worked fine with 7.0.1. Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: Look at `exception.ToString()` and find the root cause.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu that what the following statements above are "the following member on ..."

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/8.1.1-Upgrade-Guide.html